# How do I "unlock" sudo for 15 mins after login?

Tags: ssh, passwords, login

It doesn't make sense to me that after authorising myself by logging in, I then have to separately authorise myself to sudo, potentially typing the password twice. This has all come to a head recently when I have been logging in from my android phone where it takes 10 or 15 seconds to type the password in on the touchscreen instead of 2 seconds on my keyboard!

So I would ideally like to configure sudo such that after authorising myself (whether via a console login, an ssh password login or an ssh key login) sudo is unlocked for 15 minutes, as if I had typed a password for the sudo command.

So this would maintain the security benefits of automatically locking sudo if I left a console open, but giving some convenience.

I suppose the disadvantages are that I unlock sudo on every login regardless of whether I want to use sudo, and allowing sudo for ssh key logins could allow someone who compromised a private key to use sudo despite not knowing the password, which would I suppose delegate the security of the machine to the security of the private key. So a loss of a private key would transfer from a remote access vulnerability to a remote root access vulnerability...

But still, it would be quite convenient!

Comment: If you need to `sudo` every time you login, you're doing something wrong. `sudo` should be kept to computer maintenance tasks, not to daily work / home tasks...

Comment: @TomWijsman what if the machine he is logging into is a server that he doesn't use, but only maintains administrates. E.g, when I was a unix admin I administered many of my customers servers. I never visited the websites or used anything on these servers. I only administered them.

Comment: @JustinDearing: In that case `sudo` would be pointless and he would login as an account he doesn't have to run `sudo` with. Use the right account / privileges / security / tools for the right job...

Comment: @Tom Wijsman: allowing remote root logins is considered harmful by some.

Answer (score 4):

Could be done by having `pam_exec` run a command that creates the necessary timestamps in `/var/lib/sudo`.

Append the following to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and/or `/etc/pam.d/login` (but *not* `common-session` or anything like that):

```
session optional pam_exec.so /usr/lib/sudo-auth
```

The script could be:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Depends on your distro. May be /var/db/sudo, /var/spool/sudo, etc.
root="/var/lib/sudo"

if [ "$PAM_USER" ]; then
    dir="$root/$PAM_USER/"
    if [ "$PAM_TYPE" = open_session ]; then
        mkdir -p "$dir" && touch "$dir"
    fi
else
    echo "Must be run from PAM." >&2
fi
```

Requires the `tty_tickets` option to be disabled in *sudoers*, due to the way SSH (and opensshd in particular) work with ttys.

This could be modified to only authenticate specified remote hosts, either by putting `pam_access` above `pam_exec` in the PAM stack, or by just comparing `$PAM_RHOST` in the script. (Such checks wouldn't work with mobile clients, however.)

Comment: What about the 15 minutes?

Comment: @TomWijsman The standard timeout set in `sudoers` applies.

Answer (score 1):

ref: [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=763142)

```
timestamp_timeout

Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask for a passwd
again. The default is 5. Set this to 0 to always prompt for a
password. If set to a value less than 0 the user's timestamp will
never expire. This can be used to allow users to create or delete
their own timestamps via sudo -v and sudo -k respectively.
```

Edit the file:

```
sudo visudo
```

To the defaults line, add :

```
timestamp_timeout=15
```

So it looks simular to this :

```
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults env_reset,timestamp_timeout=15
```

Comment: the length of the sudo timeout wasn't really the point of the question but thanks for answering :P